# Yii2 или Yii1

Tags: framework, php, yii

Стоит ли изучать Yii v1.x.x если есть Yii v2.0.0 ?

На офсайте про это ничего сказано, кроме того, что Yii v2.0.0 еще альфа и ее не следует использовать под серьезные проекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii 2.0 можете в свободное время ковырять, чтобы потом, когда выйдет стабильная версия, можно было бы смело переходить на нее, но в продакшн пока только на ветке 1.* Я лично стал бы писать.

Answer (score 1):

Учите Yii 1. Под вторую вы уроки не скоро найдете. А перейти потом будет очень легко.